# MySQL Search column for email addresses

Tags: mysql, regex, full-text-search, email-validation

I have a table with 15 million records. I would like to search a column for email addresses (potentially multiple addresses) and place the addresses in another table. It does not have to be strict, for example '@gmail.com' | '@hotmail.com' is sufficient.

I'm using innodb, but fulltext is an option if required.

Comment: Please edit your question and include examples of what you consider to be an email address and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

step 1: Create a table  just like the table which already exists. To do this use the below query

```
create table <new Table> like <your Table Name>;
```

or if you just want the email addresses in the table use below query to crate new table

```
create table <new Table> email varchar(30);
```

step 2:  Select the records which ends with '@gmail.com'|'@hotmail.com'
and Insert them into the new table

use **email** inplace of * in select statement if you have created a table to store only email addresses

```
insert into <new Table> 
 select * from <your Table Name> 
  where email like '%@gmail.com' or email like '%@hotmail.com'
```

**edit:**
As we are using wild card search here we cannot make use of indexes on column email even if we create one

As you have mentioned that the data is 15 million there are possibilities for transaction time out

so just add **limit** and **offset** here to get the query working

for example:

```
insert into <new Table> 
 select * from <your Table Name> 
  where email like '%@gmail.com' or email like '%@hotmail.com'
limit 5000000 offset 0;
```

the above query will serach and insert the first five million records from your table(you may have to use two more queries if you use 5 million records in each transaction)

second query:

```
insert into <new Table> 
 select * from <your Table Name> 
  where email like '%@gmail.com' or email like '%@hotmail.com'
limit 5000000 offset 5000001;

insert into <new Table> 
 select * from <your Table Name> 
  where email like '%@gmail.com' or email like '%@hotmail.com'
limit 5000000 offset 10000001;
```

Comment: The records are like a caption or a bio, they may not end with the email, rather the email(s) will be within the records. If there are 15 million records will a LIKE command be a good solution?

Comment: @Anthony its good but I think it's still assuming that the email will be at the end of the record, no?

Comment: The above must work fine if you have a buffer pool size  more than 248 MB,try the query if you face any problems then ping me, happy to help :) @mils

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that says

```
"Their emails are asdf@foobar.com and theother@framis.org, ok"
```

You really need to write application code to do the task of extracting the email address(es) from the text.  It is grossly impractical to do so in SQL.  A `FULLTEXT` index won't help unless you know all the domain names; even then it won't help much.